# How to convert string to math equation?

Tags: java, string, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Parse a mathematical expression given as a string and return a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

Hello there,

I would like to ask you, if exist some way how to convert string "1+2+3" to math equation? Exist for this purpose some function or method in Java?

Thanks for hints.

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe; that one wants the solution to the equation, but this one just wants it to become an equation object of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of the standard API.

But I implemented it in my project, you can have a look here.
https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/Towel/wiki/Expression

Comment: Thank for hint, Marcos. But I am a bit confused - can you help me, please, where is saved the method called "Expression"? Thanks..

Comment: By downloading the towel jar and adding into class-path, there's a lot of useful classes there.

Answer (score 1):

This would necessarily depend on the implementation of the `Equation` class you're using. Check its API.