# Calculate multiple values from JTextField with operator precedence

Tags: java, swing

I wrote the following program. My program can provide simple arithmetic calculation like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` from the value of `JTextField`. But i need to get answer with operator precedence BMDAS (Brackets, Multiplication, Division, Addition and Subtraction) from multiple values. example: user types `10-5+8/56*(3-5+3)`: answer is `5`. I mention my implementation code. how can i update my program to get the above requirement? help me!

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class calculateValue extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton btn;
    private JTextField txt;
    String operator="+-*/()";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new calculateValue();
    }

    public calculateValue(){
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Calcuate Multiple value!");
        setLayout(null);

        txt=new JTextField();
        txt.setBounds(20,20, 150,25);
        add(txt);

        btn=new JButton("Show Answer");
        btn.setBounds(20, 50,150, 25);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn);

        setVisible(true);
    }


    public char decideOperator(String s){
        char c=' ';

        for(int i=0;i<operator.length();i++){

            if(s.contains(operator.charAt(i)+"")){
                c=operator.charAt(i);   
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int decideIndex(String s){
        int index=100;
        for(int i=0;i<operator.length();i++){

            if(s.contains(operator.charAt(i)+"")){
                index=s.indexOf(operator.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String temp=txt.getText().trim();

        double d1=Double.parseDouble(temp.substring(0, decideIndex(temp)));
        double d2=Double.parseDouble(temp.substring(decideIndex(temp)+1));

        if(decideOperator(temp)=='+') System.out.println(d1+d2);
        else if(decideOperator(temp)=='-') System.out.println(d1-d2);
        if(decideOperator(temp)=='*') System.out.println(d1*d2);
        if(decideOperator(temp)=='/') System.out.println(d1/d2);

    }
}
```

Comment: **Side note:** `setLayout(null);` is a bad practice, use [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead, they can save you a lot of work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Parse a mathematical expression given as a string and return a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form
You could just evaluate the String that the user inputs

Comment: I'd use the `ScriptEngine` for this one, as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).

Comment: i want to calculate by using operators and methods!

Comment: Try building an expression in a tree structure from your input, and then evaluating it.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a bit excessive but here is my implementation of a expression resolver:

(Given as a SSCCE):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Final Output: " + evalutateExpression("(56*3)*(4+3)"));
    }

    public static double evalutateExpression(String Input){
        //This method is extremely sensitive to bad input, try to do some clean up before sending it to the main evaluation body.
        Input = Input.replaceAll(" ", ""); //Example of a cleanup

        return Double.parseDouble(recursiveEvalutation(Input));
    }

    private static String recursiveEvalutation(String I){
        if(I.contains("(")){
            int RIndex = I.indexOf(")");
            int LIndex = I.lastIndexOf("(", RIndex);
            return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, LIndex) + recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(LIndex + 1, RIndex)) + I.substring(RIndex + 1, I.length()));
        }else if(I.contains("^") || I.contains("√")){
            int PowerIndex = I.indexOf("^");
            int SQRTIndex = I.indexOf("√");

            if(PowerIndex == -1){
                PowerIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            if(SQRTIndex == -1){
                SQRTIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            if(PowerIndex <= SQRTIndex){
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(PowerIndex + 1, I.length())) + PowerIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, PowerIndex));

                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(num1Start, PowerIndex));
                double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(PowerIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(Num1, Num2)).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }else{
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(SQRTIndex + 1, I.length())) + SQRTIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, SQRTIndex));

                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(SQRTIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(Num1)).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }
        }else if(I.contains("*") || I.contains("/")){
            int MultiplyIndex = I.indexOf("*");
            int DivideIndex = I.indexOf("/");

            if(MultiplyIndex == -1){
                MultiplyIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            if(DivideIndex == -1){
                DivideIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            if(MultiplyIndex <= DivideIndex){
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(MultiplyIndex + 1, I.length())) + MultiplyIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, MultiplyIndex));
                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(num1Start, MultiplyIndex));
                double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(MultiplyIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Num1 * Num2).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }else{
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(DivideIndex + 1, I.length())) + DivideIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, DivideIndex));
                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(num1Start, DivideIndex));
                double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(DivideIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Num1 / Num2).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }
        }else if(I.contains("+") || I.contains("−")){
            int AddIndex = I.indexOf("+");
            int MinusIndex = I.indexOf("−");

            if(AddIndex == -1){
                AddIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            if(MinusIndex == -1){
                MinusIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            if(AddIndex <= MinusIndex){
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(AddIndex + 1, I.length())) + AddIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, AddIndex));
                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(num1Start, AddIndex));
                double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(AddIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Num1 + Num2).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }else{
                int num2End = findNumberEnd(I.substring(MinusIndex + 1, I.length())) + MinusIndex + 1;
                int num1Start = findNumberStart(I.substring(0, MinusIndex));

                double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(num1Start, MinusIndex));
                double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(I.substring(MinusIndex + 1, num2End));

                String Eval = new BigDecimal(Num1 - Num2).toPlainString();

                return recursiveEvalutation(I.substring(0, num1Start) + Eval + I.substring(num2End, I.length()));
            }
        }else{
            return I;
        }
    }

    private static int findNumberEnd(String I){
        char[] expression = I.toCharArray();

        for(int x = 0;x < expression.length;x++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(expression[x]) && expression[x] != '.' && expression[x] != '-'){
                return x;
            }
        }

        return expression.length;
    }

    private static int findNumberStart(String I){
        char[] expression = I.toCharArray();

        for(int x = expression.length - 1;x >= 0;x--){
            if(!Character.isDigit(expression[x]) && expression[x] != '.' && expression[x] != '-'){
                return x + 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Follows a recursive procedure to continuously evaluate expressions left and right of the operator following operator precedence. The main evaluator being the recursiveEvalutation() method.

Limitations include:

- Undefined behavior if output reaches infinity.
- Extremely intensive (creates many many objects, especially strings)

Note that for subtraction, I am using a proper "minus sign" for the operation and a hyphen for negative numbers.

Study the code for a bit, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for parsing and preparing your expresion for calculation (it uses stack to order resolve mathematical operations precedence), or (easy solution) check the answer provided in following SO post [How to parse a mathematical expression given as a string and return a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)