# How do I make JTextField to accept no spaces from postfix string

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();        
String[] tokens = infix.split(" ");
```

Right now I am making a calculator that accepts infix strings to calculate it, but they have to be separated by spaces, how do i make it where the postfix evaluator can accept no spaces.
I.E. I have to do this

```
5 + 5 * sin ( 32 )
```

But I want it to accept that or

```
5+5*sin(32)
```

Comment: You should use a different strategy for tokenizing, not regular expressions. Like changes in the character classes (numeric, punctuations and related, letters).

Comment: BTW, for experession evaluation there are many libs in Java that can handle that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number

Comment: Why? There's no need to prohibit spaces. Just scan your tokens properly. You have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can looping through the string and check the operators and insert a space after each operator and before and parentheses too looks like.

```
for( int i=0; i < infix.Length; i++){
    if(infix[i] == '*' || infix[i] == '-' ... ){
        infix.insert(" ", i -1 );
        infix.insert(" ", i +1 );
    }
}
```

or you can remover all spaces and split the string using regex with all operators and handle the parentheses in a special case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but if you want to forbid whitespace characters in a `JTexfield` (this is what I understand by your question *"accept no spaces"*), here is how you can do:

```
yourTextField.setDocument(new PlainDocument() {
    final Pattern WHITE_SPACES = Pattern.compile("\\s+");


    public void insertString(int pOffs, String pStr, AttributeSet pA)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (WHITE_SPACES.matcher(pStr).matches()) {
            return;  // whitespace characters not allowed
        }
    }
});
```