# Is it possible to read mathematical formulae from MS-Word file & display them as is in JTextField ?

Tags: java, math, ms-word

In my project,i am reading text from word file & it is working absolutely fine but when i try to read mathematical formula then it displays nothing. I have tried using Apache POI but unable to get it through,is there any other way or a sample java program to achieve this task ?

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number

Comment: @ZeRuBuES It has nothing to do with that post.

Comment: How are the equations formatted in your word document ? Images ? Using the [built-in equation editor](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-is-Equation-Editor-6eac7d71-3c74-437b-80d3-c7dea24fdf3f) ? There are apparently [many incompatible versions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Write-insert-or-change-an-equation-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) of that, does yours by any chance give you [this kind of TeX-like text](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Linear-format-equations-and-Math-AutoCorrect-in-Word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8)?