# Detecting type of operator stored as string in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In a Java program, I have these strings:

```
a= 8,7,"+"
b=1,5,"*"
```

Each line is a separate process. I want in each line, that two number calculated with that operator. But I don't want to use any type of condition system for detecting which operator is in each line.

In fact, my main problem is detecting the type of the operator without conditions. I don't want to use the Javascript engine. I want to know is there any efficient and standard way.

Comment: You can't write strings like that in Java. Could you format the strings in the right way.

Comment: `Enum.valueOf()` would be the standard technique, or a map lookup, or a switch, but whether they avoid your condition-phobia only you can say. If you have an *actual* constraint of some kind please state it. Are you perhaps looking for a standard RPN evaluator? They're easy enough to write, but not when you specify arbitrary constraints.

Comment: Artificial limitations like this sound awfully like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution from J. Selva's response:

Improvements

1. single class
2. static block
3. better abstraction

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

```
/**
 * Created by SEA-HAWK on 23/8/15.
 */
public abstract class Expr {
    public static Map<String,Object> op;
    static{
        op=new HashMap<>();
        op.put("+", new Expr() {
            @Override
            public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
                return a + b;
            }
        });
        op.put("-", new Expr() {
            @Override
            public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
                return a - b;
            }
        });
        op.put("*", new Expr() {
            @Override
            public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
                return a * b;
            }
        });

        op.put("/", new Expr() {
            @Override
            public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
                return a / b; // decimal point loss
            }
        });
    }
    abstract public int evaluate(int a, int b);
    public static int exprEval(String expr){
        String a[]=expr.split(",");
        a[2]=a[2].replaceAll("\"","");
        return ((Expr)op.get(a[2])).evaluate(Integer.parseInt(a[0]),Integer.parseInt(a[1]));
    }
}
```

Main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x="20,10,\"*\"";
    System.out.println(x+"="+Expr.exprEval(x));
     x="20,10,\"+\"";
    System.out.println(x+"="+Expr.exprEval(x));
     x="20,10,\"-\"";
    System.out.println(x+"="+Expr.exprEval(x));
    x="20,10,\"/\"";
    System.out.println(x+"="+Expr.exprEval(x));
}
```

Output:

```
20,10,"*"=200
20,10,"+"=30
20,10,"-"=10
20,10,"/"=2
```

Note: change datatype for float/decimal value computation.

Answer (score 0):

First Split the string and store the operator in the Character variable. You can use `split()` to split a String and assign it to a String array. Access operator using the array index and assign it to a Character variable.

Now You can use `Map<Character,Object>` where you can store character and object to calculate in single structure and access later with character only without any `if-else` or `switch`.

```
Map<Character,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('+', plusObject);
map.put('-', minusObject);
map.put('*', multiplyObject);
map.put('/', divideObject);
```

To get the object type of operator, you can use `map.get(character)` it will return the object according to the character and null otherwise.

Update: Create four classes and a object for each class namely `plusObject`, `minusObject`, `multiplyObject`,`divideObject`. These are the objects that you add to `HashMap` initially. Have a `evaluate()` function in each class. Now with the returned object,  call the `evaluate()` method which will make call to  respective class. You need not check the `Object` type using any conditional statements.

Comment: my main problem is the end of your statement "Now based on the object returned...". checking object returned, needs a condition statement, i cant use conditions

Comment: Oh yes. will check out and update soon if I get any other idea.

Comment: @Fcoder did u get the update?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the postfix expression into infix mathematical expression and execute it using expression evaluator in Java or javascript(not preferred). As you recommend java, following link will help you:

[evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

[java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

Answer from above two links:

You can pass it to a BeanShell bsh.Interpreter, something like this:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(); 
interpreter.eval("result = 5+4*(7-15)");
System.out.println(interpreter.get("result"));
```

Let us know if your issue gets resolved.

Comment: OP has already excluded JavaScript. Both links are about infix notation. This question is about RPN.

Comment: the solution works only if you convert the postfix expression into infix. I should mention it explicitly. I will update it.

Comment: That would be entirely pointless. An expression in RPN is already in a suitable form for direct evaluation. Both your links convert an infix expression to RPN and then evaluate it. You can't be seriously suggesting to put an RPN->infix conversion in front of that.

Comment: May be you are right if you look just the expression of the problem. But there is constraints as well. The constraints mentioned here is "without using condition". Standard mathematical infix expression can be easily evaluated under the constraints.

Besides this, the expression is not in standard Postfix notation. Inorder to process it, the user need to reinvent the wheel and write code for processing such expression. That is additional overhead in my opinion.

Comment: Both your links contain endless conditions. The suggestion to convert RPN to infix and back to RPN is frankly preposterous. And you haven't told him how to do it. And the expressions are indeed in standard postfix notation, apart from the commas and (probably erroneous) quotes, neither of which requires an infix parsing algorithm to deal with them.

Comment: You can pass it to a BeanShell bsh.Interpreter, something like this:

Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.eval("result = 5+4*(7-15)");
System.out.println(interpreter.get("result"));

this answer is mentioned in both link. One of them accepted this solution.

Case arise here, either the expression is standard postfix or not. In my opinion it is not.

Comment: You don't need two redundant parsers to remove a couple of commas and quote characters. Period. In any case how are you going to convert RPN to infix without conditions? How are you going to do it at all? Where's your algorithm? Where's your answer?