# Convert String to math equation?

Tags: java, function, parsing, math, equation

I'm trying to figure out how to parse an input string that contains a math equation given by the user like `2x^2+3x+6` to a double that operates the String with its variables that I will define later on with a for loop.

Basically,

```
for(x=0;x<=100;x++){
    String equation = "2x^2+3x+6";
    double y = equation;
    System.out.println("Your point is x: " + x +" | Y: " + y);
}
```

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432282/4908887) but the BeanSheel Library only allowed me to use actual numbers without parameters like `"x"`.

So what I'm trying to achieve is a program that will draw a function given by the user. But for the drawing part I'm fine

Comment: The answer will depend on the language, which you have failed to specify.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to posting questions, it's java, how do i specify it in the post? Thanks

Comment: we try to solve this problem in our `compiler` course , we made a parse table from possible rules , then read our input file , and try to generate codes that refers to our math equation

Comment: but you only want to have the answer of equation , it is not neccessary to learn about compilers

Comment: But it doesn't handle parameters like 'x'

Comment: You will have to write a parser to convert it to a function then evaluate the function for different values of x and plot the results.

Comment: Yeah, i know but the question is how do i parse it

Comment: Of interest: [JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) I have not used this but appears to have what you need.

Comment: Of interst: [GitHub - darius/expr](https://github.com/darius/expr)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace every occurrence of `x` within the equation string with the string representation of `x`'s value; then you could use the post you linked to to evaluate it.

Comment: excuse me , i have a question , for this problem there are two solutions , 1- using `replace` method 2-`split` and rebuild the String using Stringbuilder , which one is efficient  ?

Comment: Try both and see.  I'd be worried about getting it to work first.