# Converting string into tokens

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split a string into tokens based on regex. However the split() gives error saying *Illegal Escape Sequencce*.

I'm trying to split the following string into tokens.

For example the following string convert into

```
1+2.0-3.145/4.0
```

this

```
1 2.0 3.145 4.0
```

&  this

```
+ - /
```

This is the regex I have written but this has some issues and gives error.

```
String[] tokens = expression.split("\\+\\-\\x\\/");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:
My end goal is to evaluate a string contaning mathematical expressions & calcualte its results. Is there any library that can be used on Android?**

Comment: Do you want to call `split` once with a `regex` to get two arrays?

Comment: It will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number

Answer (score 0):

Update your regex to `expression.split("[-+/]")`

If you want to array you can use it:

```
 List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> operands = new ArrayList<>();
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expression, "+-/", true);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken();

    if ("+-/".contains(token)) {
       operators.add(token);
    } else {
       operands.add(token);
    }
 }
```

Comment: But it won't return the special characters in a separate array in the exact order these special characters are present in the string

Comment: If you want special characters in separate array you have to slip source string to times. Or you can use this regex `(?<=[-+/])|(?=[-+/])` result will be (1, +, 2.0, -, 3.145, /, 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

It's very tricky evaluating an expression, like in which order they should be calculated luckily this has been solved before: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/

And

@Roma Khomyshyn links are useful as well.