# Why I can't I convert the string "(2+2)" to an integer (java)?

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion

I want convert a string to an integer but it doesn't work. I think the problem is that the string isn't "clean", see this example:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "(2+2)";
        int conv = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(conv);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work? I could also define `int x = (2+2);` without any problems.

What exactly is the problem here and is there an easy way to solve it?

---

*Purpose: I have just finished a code that will detect if a math expression is correct (brackets, signs, .. arithmetic stuff). As example the string input is `((8+7)*2)` and the program will return true.
But now I need to find a way to calculate this and return the solution of it, `30`. (If you want I can post my code too but I didn't want make this question seemingly long.)

Comment: Java has no built-in code that can do that.

Comment: `parseInt` meant to take a string which is a **number** and to convert it to this number.

Comment: Integer.parseInt() is expecting a number in string form so "5", "100" and so forth would work becuase they are integers. it cannot do non integer string values like "1.1", "(1)" and "(2+2)" and so forth

Comment: You can use dedicated library, such as mXparser - please follow the tutorial http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` expects a string, however it needs a number in a string format.

The `(2+2)` is a string, and it cannot compute `2+2`. So trying to convert non numeric values won't work. `()`, and `+` are non numeric values

**UPDATE:**

From my research you can use [built-in Javascript engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    String str = "2+2";
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    System.out.println(engine.eval(str));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Booo is there really no method in java? I'm not allowed to import stuff which is outside java eclipse library. Does that mean I have to code it myself, somehow?

Comment: @cnmesr If you read the answers given in the duplicate link, you'll find you can do it without adding any libraries, and without writing your own.

Comment: @cnmesr see updated code

Comment: *"The `(2+2)` is a string, and it cannot compute `2+2`."* You're right, a "string" cannot compute anything. It's just a string. --- Also, `+` can be part of a numeric value, if used as a leading sign.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't it work?

The `String` cannot be parsed to an integer due to some of the invalid characters within here:

```
"(2+2)"
```

You simply cannot parse invalid characters such as `(` `)` and `+` using `Integer.parseInt`. However, when `+` is the *only* character used and is a leading sign it's valid i.e

```
String strOne = "+2";
String strTwo = "+2345";
String strThree = "+237645";
```

etc...

> is there an easy way to solve it?

There is no built-in method to do this for you. However, you can have a look at other posts relating to your question:

- [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)
- [How to parse a mathematical expression given as a string and return a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

Comment: If you simple remove `(`, `+`, and `)`, you get `"22"`, which will parse to number `22`, which is obviously wrong, since expression should evaluate to number `4`.

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't referring to parsing _expressions_.... this is part of the question posted _What exactly is the problem here_ and I answered that.

Comment: The "problem here" is not that the string is an invalid integer *value*, it's that the `parseInt()` method is not an expression evaluator. --- Oh, and bad link there!!

Comment: hence I said  _You simply cannot parse invalid characters such as ( ) and +._ which means I am referring to the `parseInt()`.

Comment: You *can* "parse" that string, if you use an *expression parser*. Saying that the string cannot be parsed is wrong. If you had said that it cannot be parsed by `parseInt()`, you'd be correct, but you're not saying that.

Comment: Alright, I will edit my answer to get your point across, Thank you!.

Comment: `parseInt()` can parse `+`, but only as a leading sign. Saying that `parseInt()` cannot parse `+` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks once again, apologise for the wording, I am a bit off today.